# QueryBuilder alias for expr() in select() method

Tags: doctrine-orm

is there any option to set alias for  $qb->expr()->avg('e.value') in select() method of Doctrine2 query builder?

I have e.g. this query:

```
$qb->select($qb->expr()->avg('e.value'), 'e someAlias')->from('Entity', 'e');
```

But the average value is indexed by integer in the result, like this:

```
array(
  0 => array(
   'someAlias' => Entity {},
   1 => 2.5255,
  ),
);
```

Is it possible to change key of the average value to the defined string value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following to set the alias:

```
$qb->select(array(
                 $qb->expr()->select()->avg('e.value').' AS aveAlias')
                ,'e someAlias')
           )->from('Entity', 'e');
```